# Junk foods en français!

Tags: traduction, alimentation

comment traduire le mot de "junk foods" en français? La traduction par google m'a donné le mot "malboof", je cherche une autre traduction plus proche.

Answer (score 12):

« [Malbouffe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbouffe) » est bien le mot qui correspond le mieux.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse

Comment: En France, on dit aussi de plus en plus souvent "la junk-food" (de ce que j'entends).

Answer (score 9):

Dans tous les contextes, "malbouffe", comme Edouard dit, est le mot qui correspond le mieux, mais quand il est clair qu'il s'agit de les "manger", on peut dire aussi "les cochonneries."

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour le plus que vous avez apporté à ma question

Comment: Ça me semble un régionalisme québécois. Est-ce aussi utilisé en France et ailleurs ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Pour "la malbouffe", je n'en sais rien de ses origines et, en fait, c'est grace a cette question, la reponse d'Edouard, et fr.wikipedia que je le vois pour la premiere fois aujourd'hui. Pour "manger des cochonneries" je suis anglophone non-canadien (donc ni quebecois ni francais), mais ma femme francaise (de l'Oise en Picardie) vient de me preciser que cette phrase parle plutot de "manger des choses de mauvaise qualite" en general, mais que l'on peut inclure le "junkfood" comme chose de mauvaise qualite particuliere (au moins dans l'Oise).

Comment: On l'utilise aussi en Suisse. Cependant pour moi, la malbouffe, c'est plus manger des choses mauvaises pour la santé, que des cochonneries qui seraient de mauvaise qualité en plus.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur C'est courant ici (sud de la France)

Answer (score 7):

Comme le dit [Jean-Pierre Coffe](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Coffe) ... c'est tout simplement de la "merde".

Comment: +1 pour la référence au "chevalier blanc" toujours en croisade contre *la malbouffe*